# restfb api not support when user logout from facebook & access key generate every time

Tags: facebook, scala, restfb

I am using RESTFb api to post a message on facebook wall

my code is:

val facebookClient: FacebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("access_key")

def publishMessage(msg:Mesage): String = {

```
val publishMessageResponse: FacebookType = facebookClient.publish("me/feed", classOf[FacebookType],
  Parameter.`with`("message", msg))
publishMessageResponse.getId()
```

}

But this code is working only when I am login in my facebook account.If I am not login it give me the error of "user session logout". and it told me to generate the access token every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are trying to post to your own Wall.. thats why, OAuth needs to validate you are logged otherwise it wont post anything... if you where posting to a PAGE... well that's diferent you could use APP and SECRET ID's to generate AccessTokens on your website.

Comment: But I dont know how to generate a secret id using restfb api....could you please suggest me  a code so that I can post on my FB wall using restfb api in offline mode also

Comment: you can see your `app id` and `Secret id` at your app pannel at developers.facebook.com